# Gitlab runner with cassandra gitlab-ci.yml configururation

Tags: maven, cassandra, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use a gitlab runner to run a maven project integration tests that need a cassandra database. I am not sure how to write the gitlab-ci.yml file. At the moment this is what I have

```
stages:
- test

test_job:
  stage: test
  script: "mvn clean verify -DlocalIntegrationTests=true"
  when: on_success
  except:
    - production
```

Cassandra doesn't start up. How do I change the file to include cassandra starting up?

Answer (score 2):

You can run cassandra as a [service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service) and connect to it from your test stage

```
services:
  - cassandra
```

Here you will find how to [access the service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services).